# Rational Canonical Form with Sine and Cosine

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

I have $V$ which is the subspace of differentiable functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ spanned by set $S = \{\sin x, \cos x, x\sin x, x\cos x\}$.

I also have $T: V \to V$, $f \mapsto f'$ and I am supposed to find the rational canonical form of $T$.

So far, I know that $[T]_S = \begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 & 1 & 0\\1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Now, the characteristic polynomial for this matrix is $(x^2+1)^2$ and the minimal polynomial for this matrix is $x^2+1$.

The companion matrix corresponding to $x^2+1$ is $\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. 
Now, I originally thought that I simply make it into the following matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\0 & 0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

However, I am not entirely sure if this is the right format. The eigenvalues are $i$ and $-i$ and I am getting 1D eigenspace. Can someone help me from here? Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to find the matrix of $T$ with respect to the given basis? You first need that matrix before you can put it in rational canonical form.

Comment: We know that the derivatives of each of those four elements are cos$x$, -sin$x$, sin$x + x$cos$x$, and cos$x - x$sin$x$, which should be represented into four columns, but I am not sure as to how to change that into matrix.

Comment: Just write the coefficients as the columns. E.g., the first column is $\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ 1\\ 0\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$. If that's not clear, here are some links: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2452961/matrix-of-linear-transformation), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/167847/linear-transformation-matrix), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92206/matrix-of-linear-transformation). Or for the general procedure: [4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Finding_the_matrix_of_a_transformation).

Comment: That was relatively simple. Thanks. After I find the matrix, should I move on to find the rational canonical form by methods similar to this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2236919/find-the-rational-canonical-form-of-a-matrix-from-its-minimal-and-characteristic)?

Comment: Yes, and in this case it suffices to just compute the minimal polynomial of the matrix $A$. So computing the characteristic polynomial is a good start. (In general you would have to compute all the invariant factors of $A$ in order to determine the rational canonical form.) If you figure it out, please post your answer below!

Comment: Hello, I think I almost got it, but I have a slight issue. I found that the minimal polynomial to be $x^2+1$ and the corresponding companion matrix to be $\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1\\1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. Is it just having these two matrices in a "diagonal" of a 4 by 4 matrix? I am getting rank of each eigenspace to be 1 for both $i$ and $-i$, the two eigenvalues of this matrix and I am not sure if having just two of this matrix on a diagonal would be the correct rational canonical form

Comment: Your matrix looks wrong, specifically the last column. The last column should have a $1$ and a $-1$ since the corresponding function is $\cos(x) - x\sin(x)$.